# Next.js doesn't pick up variables from the .env file

Tags: next.js

I want to use a variable from the `.env` file, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. You used an empty string.
```

**code**

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

**.env**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Next.js you should declare your environment variables in a `.env.local` file.
For more informations check the official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

However, as suggested by @juliomalves, you can declare your environment variables in a `.env.*` file, making sure that you respect the [environment variables load order](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order).

Comment: Using `.env` is also fine, as long as you don't have any other more specific `.env.*` file present (which may be why OP was experiencing the issue). See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order.